# svn log output is not displaying in browser in php page

Tags: php, svn

I have a query in my php page, Could you please help me to resolve that. In php page i want to do SVN list of the repo, so i written the code as below.

page name: svn_list.php

```
<?php
$cmd = '/usr/bin/svn list repo_name';
exec($cmd, $output);
$output = implode("\n", $output) . "\n";
echo $output;
?>
```

If i run this script in putty by giving command "php svn_list.php" is working fine. it list out the files. but i want to see this output in browser. If i open the php file in browser it shows empty.
Even i tried with using following PHP header at the top of the PHP Code, eventhough it's not displaying. Please help me on this.

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem , here , to me seems to be with the user level access.

Not sure but you might have checked the script in cli with the user (may be a root user) who has the privilege of running the svn list command and hence must be giving the result and the user (for Apache which might be running as user www-data and group www-data or as user apache and group apache) might not have that permission for running the svn list command.

Try checking the permission level.
http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache

Answer (score 0):

Check where is configuration file:

```
   php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

In this file, check for "disable_functions".

If "exec" function is not disabled, check logs of www server.